# $rootScope is lost after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a data-binding to `$rootScope.someArray` in my **someData.view.html**. I have written a Data service to load data and populate `$rootScope.someArray` and have called that service in my App's "**run**" method. Now If I am on the **someData.view.html** page and hit refresh(F5) all the data vanishes. Although if I go to home again and navigate to this html page, every thing comes back. 
When I put a debug point on the place in **DataService** code where `$rootScope.someArray` is being populated, I can see data getting fetched from the backend but somehow it's lost.

Answer (score 0):

Basically angular won't have the data on refresh. If you want retain you data, you need to use,

session service or local storage service based on your need (Don't forget to clear on log out).

But Putting all the data in local storage services or putting sensitive data in the local storage services is not advisable. So you need to call the Back end method and assign the data to the variable in the controller init (call using ng-init).

> Note : Don't dump your array of data in RootScope. AngularJs team
>   itself suggesting that not to use. Instead of this use Angular
>   Services (not Factory) and make use this services where ever you want.